# Не работает Auth через api.php в Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, postman, laravel-5.7

Пытаюсь подключить vue к Laravel и вывести без перезагрузок данные из таблицы, которые принадлежат авторизованному пользователю (записи с user_id). И с последним как раз есть проблемы.

Процесс:

Создал ресурс app\Http\Resources\DataListResource.php для получения json

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        'list_type_id' => $this->list_type_id
    ];
}
```

Через api.php подключаю маршрут для vue (тестирую пока в программе Postman)

```
Route::get('test', 'TestController@list');
```

В контроллере мне нужно отфильтровать записи таблицы по id авторизованного пользователя (типа пользователь авторизовался, перешел на страницу и ему показываются только записи, которые ему принадлежат - с его user_id ). Поэтому в контроллере:

```
public function list()
{
      $user_id = Auth::id();
      $datalist = DataList::where('user_id', $user_id )->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
      return DataListResource::collection($datalist);
}
```

При этом в программе Postman при запросе domen.ru/api/test получаю пустой массив [].

Но если изменю в котроллере на:

```
public function list()
{
      $user_id =4; //просто поставил цифру 4 вместо auth
      //все остальное без изменений
}
```

..то в Postman получаю правильный заполненный json массив.

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 56,
        "name": "зеленый список",
        "description": null,
        "user_id": 4,
        "list_type_id": 2
    }
```

При этом use Auth; подключен к контроллеру. И если использовать обычный web.php и вывод в шаблон blade (через return view…) то Auth работает и дает мне нужный id. Я получаю id авторизованного пользователя и сортирую записи. А в api.php (точнее в контроллере, который им вызывается) не работает.

Я так понимаю, что если обращаться к контроллеру через api.php, Auth не работает. Это так?

Тогда как в контроллере, вызываемом с помощью api.php получить user_id? Буду благодарен за  пример (я новичок в программировании и пока плохо владею терминологией и только начинаю разбираться во всех этих процессах).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. Оказывается, чтобы подключиться к vue в Laravel не обязательно api.php. Я создал обычный маршрут в web.php

```
Route::get('/json/datalist', 'TestController@json_datalist');
```

и метод в контроллере

```
public function json_datalist()
{
      $datalist = DataList::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
      return DataListResource::collection($datalist);
}
```

Который фильтрует записи по ид пользователя и все это передает во vue. При этом postman продолжает показывать пустой массив и я так думаю потому что он не авторизован) Не знаю правда насколько так корректно делать т.к. на ютубе изучал пример с api.php

Кто будет делать по моему примеру - не забудьте создать ресурс для конвертации в json через php artisan make:resource NameResource определить там записи в массиве (пример выше) и подключить к контроллеру через 
use App\Http\Resources\NameResource as NameResource;
и
use Auth;
для работы с авторизацией